# Does RIPEMD-320 provides the same level of security as RIPEMD-160?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIPEMD) from Wikipedia claims that "256- and 320-bit versions of RIPEMD provide the same level of security as RIPEMD-128 and RIPEMD-160, respectively".
Is that true or false ? And why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true; it says so in the [paper](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ebosselae/ripemd160/pdf/AB-9601/AB-9601.pdf), which is referenced on that page.

This is the case because RIPEMD-256 is constructed using RIPEMD-128, and RIPEMD-320 is constructed using RIPEMD-160. From the paper:

> RIPEMD-128 and RIPEMD-160 have already two parallel lines, hence a
> double length extension (to 256 respectively 320 bits) can be
> constructed without the need for two parallel instances: it is
> sufficient to omit the combination of the two lines at the end of
> every application of the compression function. We propose to introduce
> interaction between the lines by swapping after round 1 the contents
> of registers A and A’, after round 2 the contents of registers B and
> B’, etc.

[This](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ebosselae/ripemd160.html) page also links some pseudocode and summarises the above as:

> RIPEMD-256 and RIPEMD-320 are constructed from, respectively,
> RIPEMD-128 and RIPEMD-160 by initializing the two parallel lines with
> different initial values, omitting the combination of the two lines at
> the end of every application of the compression function, and
> exchanging a chaining variable between the 2 parallel lines after each
> round.